# jQuery autocomplete problem: how to handle 'Not in list' case

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me clarify: I'm using standard jQuery autocomplete plugin (bassistanse.de) and bind it to a KeyValueCollection serialized to JSON (ASP.NET MVC). All works fine, except I want to be able to notify user when he/she types in a value which isn't present in DB, i.e. value not in list.

What are possible ways of solving this?

Ideally, I would like to handle both 'first time error' and 'error after valid choice' cases.

Handling 'blur' event doesn't help, since user can click drop down item (effectively losing focus), and after that the selection immediately will have been made.

Thank you.

Comment: I havent been using the site long, but you should add the 'asp.net-ajax' tag for more help.

Comment: I'm not using asp.net-ajax, I'm using jQuery.

Comment: Please explain 'first time error' and 'error after valid choice'.

Comment: First time error: I open web page and enter invalid value into autocomplete box. Error after valid choice: I open web page and enter correct value into text box. Then I change my mind and append some characters to a selected value (March, => March99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/) page, the second example exludes the current month, but if you start typing 'September', the bottom of the page produces a message that says 'No Match'. This is done when the built in ['result'](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result#handler) event is fired and it's parameter 'data' is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The only gotcha was to discover that it only worded in latest version. I've been using 1.0.2 where result handler wasn't being called upon mismatch.